# Unity coroutine "WaitForSeconds" is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to create a function that after some time you go back to the menu. I'm using coroutines to do it but it isn't working

I used:

```cs
StartCoroutine(BackToMenu(3));
```

To invoke the following function:

```cs
IEnumerator BackToMenu(float time)
{
    Debug.Log($"you are going back to the menu in {time} seconds");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Debug.Log("back to menu");
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Glitch Main Menu");
}
```

The console is only logging the first Log, after the return it just doesn't do anything. It's my first time using coroutines so I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Are you disabling the object the coroutine is running on? Would help to see a [mcve] in case there's important parts you've left out.

Comment: @LLorenzo Boga I tested your code and it worked fine, maybe the problem is from other part of the code. Please show more details of the code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks, that was it. The class that calls the function is singleton si that instance got destroyed before calling the function. thanks!